# Как обратиться к хэшу, чьё имя хранится в переменной?

Tags: perl

Есть хэш.
Есть переменная, в которой хранится имя этого хэша. Как обратиться к элементу этого хэша, с помощью этой переменной, т.е. не используя имя самого хэша?

```
my %h;
$h{a} = 'qwerty';
my $v = 'h';

??? print $"$v"{a};
```

Answer (score 3):

Например так: `print eval "\$$v\{a\}";`

или так:

```
our %h;
$h{a} = 'qwerty';
our $v = 'h';

no strict 'refs';
print $$v{a};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
${ "имя переменной" }

my %h;
$h{a} = 'qwerty';
my $v = 'h'; # можно писать даже так: ${ v } =  'h';
print ${ $v }{ a };

# Любое имя для переменной:
${ '^%^GDYFGYHG&(*&^' } = 33;
@{ list } = ( 1,2,3 ); # знак ' не требуется, т.к. не используем спец символы
%{ '%$#' } = ( a=>1, b=>2 );
```